# Extended use of the Complement of direction and 把。

Tags: direction-complement

I was under the impression that you cannot say:

> *我把他的名字想不起來。

Because our book says you cannot apply 把 to 可能補語。
But now my fellow students pointed out that 想不起來 is no 可能補語, but rather 趨向補語的引申用法。
[image]
Does the same rule apply, or is the sentence correct? My grammar book says that 趨向補語 frequently acts as 可能補語 (for example: 自行車壞了，我騎不回去了！). It seems only natural, that the same restrictions should apply.

When I have 想不起來 on its own without 把，can I even unambiguously say, whether it is the negative of 可能補語 or 趨向補語？

Comment: 把... structure can not be used negatively. You can say *把他的名字想起來*, but can't say *把他的名字想不起來*. Sometimes, 别把....denotes negative, but meaning will be slightly changed.

Comment: 趋向补语 and 结果补语 （overlapping anyhow) suitably transformed (with 不 or 得）become 可能补语，想不起來 would seem to be such a transformed 趋向补语

Comment: 把他的名字想起來 is imperative, not declarative. You can make this negative, but it would become 不要把他的名字想起來

Comment: @fefe the question is if and why the starred sentence is wrong.

Comment: @Ludi yes, so this is only a comment. And it is in response to dan's comment ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply 把 to a verb phrase with potential particle because 把 is a dispositive marker. A dispositive marker marks an object to be disposited of by a verb. For example: in (把)他趕走. the object(他) is being disposited of by the verb 趕走 (chase away).

When a potential particles (得 or 不) is inserted between a verb and its resultive/ directional particle, that verb becomes a potential verb. For example:  趕走= chase away;  趕得走 = able to chase away.  It can no longer be applied to [dispositive marker + object] structure which requires an active verb at the end.

Example: in 我(趕走)他 , (趕走) is an action verb; in 我(趕得走)他, (趕得走)is a potential verb- *You can, but you are not actively preforming the verb*)

For the same reason, 我把他的名字(想起來- *active verb*) is correct, but  我把他的名字(想不/得起來- *potential verb*) is incorrect

To make '我把他的名字想起來' negative , you have to modify 把 with a negative marker like 沒 or 未 , for example: "我(沒)把他的名字想起來"

> *When I have 想不起來 on its own without 把，can I even unambiguously say, whether it is the negative of 可能補語 or 趨向補語？*

Without 把, there's no object to be disposited of,  '想起來' (active verb) or '想不起來/'想得起來 (potential verb) can be applied.

The sentence can be "我(想起)他的名字來" or, "我(想得起)他的名字來,  "我(想不起)他的名字來"- (*you are not actively preforming the verb*)